# Tailwind CSS is removing the default styles for html elements (headings, inputs, select and buttons etc). Why?

Tags: css, reactjs, user-interface, tailwind-css, vite

I am working on a web application and I am using React-JS for front-end. I have decided to use tailwind-css for styling purposes. But when I installed the tailwind-css in my project, some how the default css styles for the html elements were gone. Can you please tell me the reasons and what are the possible solutions for it.

Note -> I am using vite tooling.

Answer (score 0):

After posting this question I was going through the documentation of the tailwind-css and I got the answer. This is has something to do with "Preflight" which removes some of the default styles. If you want to know more about the preflight just visit the official documentation of tailwind-css

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Ah, you didn't disable preflight!

In this case the solution is quite simple.

Inside the `tailwind.config.js` file, you will see something like this

```
module.exports = {

}
```

Simply add this inside.

```
corePlugins: {
   preflight: false,
}
```

This disables preflight and allows for default css stylings. Note that you can still use tailwind with this.