# Tailwindcss interfering with Sanity's PortableText/react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css, sanity

I'm working on a project that uses Sanity CMS rich text, and PortableText that parses through the text so it renders with proper formatting (ie. bullet points, bolded text, etc).

Wanting to learn TailwindCSS, I installed it to my project and noticed that some (not all) of the css gets overwritten (eg. bolded text is fine, but headings & bullet points aren't).

I've tried a lot of things and can't seem to figure it out, and learned it was a tailwind issue by rebuilding my repo several times. The text showed correctly when not installing tailwind. Another clue was commenting out `import '@/styles/globals.css'`, which showed the correct rich text formatting from Sanity. So tailwind seems to be overwriting what PortableText is doing.

How do I prevent this from happening? Any help is appreciated.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "type": "module",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "astro dev",
    "start": "astro dev",
    "build": "astro build",
    "preview": "astro preview",
    "astro": "astro"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@astrojs/react": "^3.0.2",
    "@astrojs/tailwind": "^5.0.0",
    "@portabletext/react": "^3.0.7",
    "@radix-ui/react-slot": "^1.0.2",
    "@sanity/client": "^6.4.12",
    "@sanity/image-url": "^1.0.2",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.22",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "astro": "^3.0.12",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
    "clsx": "^2.0.0",
    "lucide-react": "^0.279.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "tailwind-merge": "^1.14.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.6.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.7.0",
    "eslint": "^8.49.0",
    "eslint-plugin-astro": "^0.29.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.7.1"
  }
}
```

globals.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

astro.config.mjs

```
import { defineConfig } from 'astro/config';
import react from '@astrojs/react';

import tailwind from '@astrojs/tailwind';

// https://astro.build/config
export default defineConfig({
  integrations: [
    react(),
    tailwind({
      applyBaseStyles: false,
    }),
  ],
});
```

tailwind.config.cjs

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  darkMode: ['class'],
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    './components/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    './app/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    './src/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    container: {
      center: true,
      padding: '2rem',
      screens: {
        '2xl': '1400px',
      },
    },
    extend: {
      keyframes: {
        'accordion-down': {
          from: { height: 0 },
          to: { height: 'var(--radix-accordion-content-height)' },
        },
        'accordion-up': {
          from: { height: 'var(--radix-accordion-content-height)' },
          to: { height: 0 },
        },
      },
      animation: {
        'accordion-down': 'accordion-down 0.2s ease-out',
        'accordion-up': 'accordion-up 0.2s ease-out',
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [require('tailwindcss-animate')],
};
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "extends": "astro/tsconfigs/strict",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "jsxImportSource": "react",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So the issue is due to the base styling coming from Tailwind (from globals.css) overwriting regular styling. Setting preflight: false in the to tailwind.config.cjs helps, but impacts other styling. Not a great solution but at least it's pointing to the root issue if this helps anyone else. [Here's a related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76028495/tailwind-css-is-removing-the-default-styles-for-html-elements-headings-inputs)